# Databinding Table References

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two tables tblCarrier and `tblCustomer`. Both tables are `INNER JOIN` and have the same column name which is company name. The problem is when I use the databinding process

`<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CompanyName")%>`  to get the back the customer company name, it gives me back the carrier company name. What I notice from my query is that it gets back the company name based on the order sequence in the query statement.

For example

> "SELECT
>   tblCarrier.CarrierID,tblLoadMaster.Salesperson,tblLoadMaster.Status,
>   tblCarrier.CompanyName, tblCustomer.CompanyName"

This T-SQL statement will bring back the carrier company name, but if I were to put the `tblCustomer.CompanyName` before `tblCarrier.CompanyName`, it will then bring back the  customer company.

Is there way to databind the columns to get the results based on the cross reference table?

Comment: Can you check by giving "tblCustomer.CompanyName" in Eval instead of "CompanyName"

Comment: Tried that process and it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You could alias the conflicting column names

```
SELECT tblCarrier.CarrierID,tblLoadMaster.Salesperson,tblLoadMaster.Status,  
  tblCarrier.CompanyName as Car_CompanyName, 
  tblCustomer.CompanyName as Cus_CompanyName;
```

And then use the alias instead of the column names in the Eval call.

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Cus_CompanyName")%>
```

Comment: I was just going to post the above code, it is a sql problem not asp.net binding problem .